# Python for .NET: System.BadImageFormatException when embedding

Tags: python, .net, embed, python.net

I'm trying to embed Python in my .NET application.

I'm using Python 3.6.1 64-bit on Windows 10 and I have installed pythonnet 2.3.0 from PyPi using pip.

I've referenced `Python.Runtime.dll` from `C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages` and have both `Path` and `PYTHONHOME` environment variables pointed to `C:\Program Files\Python36\`.

When I use .NET in Python everything is OK.

```
import clr
from System.Drawing import Point
p = Point(5, 5)
print(p)
```

prints `{X=5,Y=5}` as expected.

But when I call Python from .NET I get `System.BadImageFormatException`. For example, when calling `Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize();` :

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Python.Runtime, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.'

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are probably calling from 32-bit .NET process, but your Python 3.6 is 64-bit. Try to run nPython.exe from pythonnet solution.

Comment: @denfromufa Thank you! I've just forgot to change `Platform target` in my project from `Any CPU` to `x64`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As denfromufa said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416784/python-for-net-system-badimageformatexception-when-embedding#comment75833728_44416784), I was just calling from a 32-bit .NET process.